# Nested ajax function yielding no result when using POST and isset in PHP script

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I wrote a function that contained a nested ajax function that will be triggered once a form is submitted. What the function does is it submits the form data, reloads the newly added database information to the table and finally checks if all the results have been entered into the table.

At this stage, once the submit button is clicked nothing happens, however once I remove the `if (isset($_POST['submit']))` in the PHP file, the code works, although it gives a couple of undefined index errors. Regardless of using `isset`, the final part of the ajax code that checks if all the results are entered works all the time.

Why is it that the ajax wont allow the `(isset($_POST['submit']))` to talk with the `url: "../server/insert_tests.php?submit",`? Is there a possible solution for this problem?

This is the Ajax function that will be called once the form is submitted:

```
function formSubmit() {
  $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "../server/insert_tests.php?submit",
    data: $('#frmBox').serialize(),
    success: function(message){
      $('#success').html(message).fadeIn('fast').delay(3000).fadeOut('slow');

      var sample_id = $("#sample_id").val();
      var url = "../server/insert_tests.php?query=";

      $.ajax({
        type: "GET", 
        url: url + sample_id,                 
        success: function(results) {
          $("#tests").html(results);

          var order_id = $("#order_id").val();
          var url2 = "../server/insert_tests.php?button_message=";

          $.ajax({
            type: "GET", 
            url: url2 + order_id,             
            success: function(button) {
              $("#button_message").html(button);
            }
          }); 
        }
      }); 
    }
  });  
  var form = document.getElementById('frmBox').reset();
  return false;
}
```

Here is the form:

```
<div class="result_input">
  <form id="frmBox" onsubmit="return formSubmit();">                   
    <table id="tests">
    </table>
    <input type="submit" id="submit" value="Submit Result" style="width: 50%;border-radius: 5px; background-color: white; border: 2px solid green;color: green;"> 
  </form>         
</div>
```

And the PHP:

```
session_start();

//Current time as "hour:min:seconds" for all time stamps
$time = date("H:i:s");
//Current date as "year-month-day" for all date stamps
$date = date("Y-m-d");

$output = '';
$analyst = '';
$order_id = '';


require 'dbh.php';


$analyst = $_SESSION['logged_in_id'];

if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
    $n = test_input(count($_POST['result_id']));
    for($i = 0; $i<$n; ++$i) {
        $result_id =test_input($_POST['result_id'][$i]);
        $order_id = test_input($_POST['order_id'][$i]);
        $sample_id = test_input($_POST['sample_id'][$i]);
        $detected = test_input($_POST['detected'][$i]);
        $result = test_input($_POST['result'][$i]);
        $m_analysis_id = test_input($_POST['m_analysis_id'][$i]);



        if ($result_id == '') {

            $sql = "INSERT INTO results_database (order_id, sample_id, detected, result, m_analysis_id, analyst) VALUES ('$order_id', '$sample_id', '$detected', '$result', '$m_analysis_id', '$analyst');";
            mysqli_query($conn, $sql);

        } else {

            $sql = "UPDATE results_database SET order_id='$order_id', sample_id='$sample_id', detected='$detected', result='$result', m_analysis_id='$m_analysis_id', analyst='$analyst' WHERE id='$result_id';";
            mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
        }

    }

    $order_id1 = test_input($_POST['order_id'][0]);
    $sample_id1 = test_input($_POST['sample_id'][0]);

    $sql1 = "UPDATE samples_database SET s_status='Analysis Started', s_time1='$time', s_date1='$date' WHERE id='$sample_id1';";
    $sql1 .= "UPDATE order_database SET order_status='Analysis Started' WHERE id='$order_id1';";

    mysqli_multi_query($conn, $sql1);

    $output1 = '';
    $output1 .= '<h3 style="text-align:center;color:green;">Result was successfully added!</h3>';

    echo $output1;

    function test_input($data) {
        $data = trim($data);
        $data = stripslashes($data);
        $data = htmlspecialchars($data);
        return $data;
    }
}


if (isset($_GET['query'])) {
    require 'dbh.php';

    $id = $_GET['query'];
    $query = "SELECT * FROM samples_database WHERE sample_id=$id;";
    $result = mysqli_query($conn, $query);
    $input = mysqli_fetch_array($result);
    $input1 = $input['micro_analysis'];
    $env_sam_id = $input['env_sam_id'];
    $c_sam_id = $input['c_sam_id'];
    $order_id = $input['order_id'];
    $rows = explode(',', $input1);

    if (count($rows) > 0 ) {
        $output .= '
        <thead>
        <tr>
        <th colspan="1"></th>
        <th>Tests ('.$env_sam_id.' <i>'.$c_sam_id.'</i>)</th>
        <th>Detected</th>
        <th>Result</th>
        </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>';
        foreach ($rows as $row) {
            $query2 = "SELECT * FROM microbiology_analysis_database WHERE id=$row"; 
            $result2 = mysqli_query($conn, $query2);
            $input2 = mysqli_fetch_array($result2);
            $analysis = $input2['m_analysis'];


            $query3 = "SELECT * FROM results_database WHERE m_analysis_id=$row AND order_id=$order_id AND sample_id=$id;"; 
            $result3 = mysqli_query($conn, $query3);
            $input3 = mysqli_fetch_array($result3);
            $result_id = $input3['id'];
            $result = $input3['result'];
            $detected = $input3['detected'];

            $output .= 
            '<tr>
            <td>
            <input class="hidden" name="result_id[]" id="result_id" value="'.$result_id.'" readonly>
            <input class="hidden" name="m_analysis_id[]" id="m_analysis_id" value="'.$row.'" readonly>
            <input class="hidden" name="order_id[]" id="order_id" value="'.$order_id.'" readonly>
            <input class="hidden" name="sample_id[]" id="sample_id" value="'.$id.'" readonly></td>


            <td>'.$analysis.'</td>
            <td><input name="detected[]" class="result_input" type="text" id="detected" value="'.$detected.'"></td>
            <td><input name="result[]" class="result_input" type="text" id="result" value="'.$result.'"></td>
            </tr>';
        }
        $output .= '</tbody> ';
    }
    echo $output;
}



if (isset($_GET['button_message'])) {
    require 'dbh.php';

    $order_id = $_GET['button_message'];

    $sql = "SELECT * FROM samples_database WHERE order_id = $order_id AND micro_analysis !='';";

    $end_result = 0;
    $count_query = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($count_query)) {
        $end_result += substr_count($row['micro_analysis'], ",") + 1;
    }

    $sql2 = "SELECT * FROM results_database WHERE order_id = $order_id AND m_analysis_id !='' AND detected !='';";

    $count_query2 = mysqli_query($conn, $sql2);
    $end_result2 = mysqli_num_rows($count_query2);

    $output2 = '';

    if ($end_result !== $end_result2) { 

        $output2 .= '<h3 style="color: darkred;text-align: center;">Analysis not yet completed for report submission! Total analyses: '.$end_result.' Results entered: '.$end_result2.'</h3>';

    } else { 

        $output2 .= '<a type="button" style="text-decoration:none;color:white;" href="../server/server.php?complete_m_results='.$order_id.'"><button style="width: 50%;border-radius: 5px; background-color: white; border: 2px solid green;color: green;" type="button" class="button">Complete Order</button></a>';

    }

    echo $output2;

}
```

Comment: Why don't you just use `$post` ? Like `var sbmt = $('#frmBox').serialize();
$.post('../server/insert_tests.php', {submit: sbmt} function(data) {
  /*optional stuff to do after success */
});`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Parameters submitted as part of the URL e.g. `?submit` need to be accessed via `$_GET`, not `$_POST`. From the manual for [`$_GET`](http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.get.php):

> An associative array of variables passed to the current script via the URL parameters (aka. query string). **Note that the array is not only populated for GET requests, but rather for all requests with a query string.**

So in your code, you should change:

```
if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
```

to

```
if (isset($_GET['submit'])) {
```

Comment: Alright so I removed the `?submit` and now I get a lot of Undefined Index Notice errors...

Comment: Leave the `?submit`, but you need to check `if (isset($_GET['submit'])) {`, not `if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {`